# Auto logout after X minutes, Android

Tags: java, android, timeout

I'm looking to implement a feature that logs out the user after X minutes of inactivity. After going through a similar answer on SO, the suggested method seems to be to -

- Have a timer running in the background. Schedule it to timeout after x minutes.
- In every function where the user interacts with the app (basically all event handlers), call a method that resets the timer.

I can't think of anything better than this myself, but it's seems to be a huge pain even for a medium sized application that has 6-7 different screens and a whole bunch of UI components. Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have a timer running in the background. Schedule it to timeout after x minutes.

No and yes. Use a timer if you're implementing it in a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or in an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). Otherwise, don't.

> In every function where the user interacts with the app (basically all event handlers), call a method that resets the timer.

That solution would be hard to maintain.

You should have an `IntentService` (demonstrating article [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)) running in the background that can easily implement a [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) or a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and make the runnable code inside it fire a broadcast to your activities. In your activities you can easily add a [`BroadcastReciever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and in that case you can log out the user if time is out. You can start your service when your application isn't visible to the user.

Comment: Not sure I follow you completely. Please correct me if I'm wrong - When the application is about to become invisible, I start a service. When the application becomes visible again, I stop it. While the service is started, I have some sort of timer that will fire on 30 minutes and have a `BroadcastReceiver` in all my activities. When they receive a broadcast, they perform any cleanup, call activity.finish() and exit?

Comment: Well, how do you want your application to be? In your question it sounds like you wanted the user to be logged out and in this case you should logout the user when receiving it, not call `finish()` on the `Activity` itself. Of course you're free to do what you want, I might have misunderstood your question. Otherwise, it seems good.

Comment: Well, actually that's a separate question, but yes, I should probably just logout in this case, and when each activity is displayed, I should check to see if the user's logged in and call `activity.finish()` if not. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and restart it from [`onUserInteraction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) in every `Activity()`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would go about this:

1) Create a global variable to represent a time log

2) During the onStop call for each activity, update the global variable with the current time.

3) During the onResume call for each activity, compare the current time with the global variable time to see how much time has passed

Comment: but in doing this we have to update the global variable at each activity like (mouse click or mouse move etc) which is really a pain if the application is big.. is there a way to trigger this update internally whenever an activity happens in the application ?

Comment: Ah. I understand the problem now. I thought you wanted to measure the time an application was in the background. My mistake, sorry!
 
This problem is tricky. The only suggestion I can make is to extend the OnTouch/OnClick listener objects and add an 'update' function. Use your new OnTouch/OnClick objects throughout your application

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I wanted to implement for myself.
Here is a "library" I made: https://github.com/zoltanersek/android-timeout-activity

Usage:

```
public class TestActivity extends TimeoutActivity {

@Override protected void onTimeout() {
 // logout
}

@Override protected long getTimeoutInSeconds() {
  return 15 * 60; // 15 minutes
}

}
```