# Is there a Violation of interface-segregation principle in CountDownTimer class in Android?

Tags: java, android, solid-principles

`CountDownTimer` is a [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) which we are using to implement (kind-of) session timeout.

My work is based on the theory explained in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705216/auto-logout-after-x-minutes-android). We start the `CountDownTimer`  in `Activity` and when there is no user interaction with app, this `CountDownTimer` expires and its `onFinish()` is getting called and we logout the user from app from within this method.

With every user interaction with app, we reset the `CountDownTimer` in Activity.

The code for it is working fine but I am concerned of a possible violation of [interface-segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) here.

We have to implement `onTick(long millisUntilFinished)` along with `onFinish()` as both are `abstract`. I don't need to implement this `onTick` method as all I am interested in is when my `CountDownTimer` expires, that is `onFinish()`  but still implememted `onTick(long millisUntilFinished)` it being `abstract`.

Or should I use something different than `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: The interface is pretty tight, two methods that are usually used in tandem.  In your case, since **onTick** is a void method and the hassle of implementing it is minimal, I'd implement onTick with a comment  //not used and be done with it.

Comment: @dbugger correct, I too had empty onTick with the comment that this is part of interface. since its tiny code not much of an issue there. I was just curious about it as that class is part of Android framework, which is well-written code which adhere to best code principles almost always!