# Automatic logout of Android App

Tags: java, android

I know there are several answers to this question, but it isn't working for me, currently my code is:

```
public class LogoutService extends Service {

    public static CountDownTimer timer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        timer = new CountDownTimer(1 * 60 * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Some code
                Log.v(TAG, "Service Started");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v(TAG, "Call Logout by Service");
                // Code for Logout
                stopSelf();
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in every activity I have:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    LogoutService.timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    LogoutService.timer.cancel();
}
```

But I get a "Unable to resume activity java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference" when I try to start any of my activities that contain this code. My application isn't too complicated, it's completely offline, so no web service calls or anything, I just need to go back to my login activity after x minutes. Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the one I used: [Auto logout after X minutes, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705216/auto-logout-after-x-minutes-android) and http://androidjug.blogspot.com/2015/10/auto-logout-after-15-minutes-due-to.html

Comment: First start your service

Comment: How do I start service and where?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Oh alright, I followed your link and used the below code in my onCreate, but I still get the error. Any idea why?


    startService(new Intent(this, LogoutService.class));

Answer (score 0):

You aren't starting the service, so you aren't allocating the timer.  Really you should not be using a static for this.

Comment: I started the service in my onCreate, but I'm still getting the same error.